# deb packages download with wget

Tags: download, package, deb

I need to download a deb package from pkgs.org, `gpg-agent_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb` to be specific.
I tried

```
wget https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/gpg-agent_2.2.19-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

But I get a

> 403 Forbidden

The general question therefore is how do I download a .deb file from this site.
There is no support or contact information on the site.
Tried lots of other things like trying to get to it using Filezilla but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

If I had scrolled down the webpage I would have found the information that I needed and it would have given me the correct url which in my instance was
`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnupg2/gpg-agent_2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb`

Now it works

Regards
Joseph Shanahan